# Creating a subversion repository from a visual studio project

Tags: visual-studio, svn

I am trying to use subversion and am having a tough time.  The documentation is unclear at times.  Basically I am trying to figure out how to merge but that causes conflicts because of files that should never have been included in the repository.

I issued a svn import command.  That put the *.suo and bin and obj folders in the repository.  I then added the svn:ignore command to the top level folder of each dll to ignore *.suo, *.user bin and obj.  But this still causes problems because compiling the project (50+ dlls) creates these folders and since they existed in the repository before this causes conflicts.

So I presume that I need to create the repository without these files.  But I can't use the svn:ignore command without a working directory as far as I know.  Maybe the tortoise gui can do it but I am trying to learn the tool itself.  If it can not do this I would like to know.

Thanks
JM

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're asking. Are you importing or merging? What have you tried? What happened? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: I'm importing.  I am learning this tool so I have little expectations.  I imported, made a branch, made some changes and tried to merge.  I received conflicts because of *.suo files.  Realizing that they should not be in there (along with *.user, bin and obj) I tried deleting them and adding them to the svn:ignore.  But that didn't work because they existed previously in the repository.  So it seems to me that I must create a repository without them.

Comment: If you use a plug-in like Agent SVN it will let you do the Add to Source Control from inside the VS IDE and it will create the correct file/folder structure in the SVN repository. Note: I'm the author of that plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

First rule of merging: always have a [pristine checkout](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.examine) as the merge target. That means, only versioned files in the checkout, no modified, added, deleted, unversioned or ignored files and folders. I ensure this by using TortoiseSVN's Cleanup command, ticking everything:

[image: Pristine-through-Cleanup]

From what I understand about your question, it seems you've SVN-Added-and-Committed some files and folders that should have been `svn:ignore`d in the first place. So, using TortoiseSVN, select the files, and choose `TortoiseSVN -> Unversion and add to ignore list -> *.ext`:

[image: TortoiseSVN's Unversion-Ignore Feature]

Do the same for the folders, but `Delete and ignore by name` instead.

What this does is an `svn delete`followed by adding an `svn:ignore` property on the containing folder with the file/folder pattern set.

And then, commit the changes.

After that, do the SVN Cleanup as detailed above to delete the now-ignored files and folders, and then conduct your merge.

It's worth noting that [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) automatically adds the `svn:ignore` patterns for projects newly added to a solution.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer was to use the `global-ignores` in the config file which can be found in:

> C:\Users\%User%\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\config

I tried using the `svn:ignore` and that appears to work in the short term.  Try to do a merge and it causes conflicts. The config file should look like this:

```
[miscellany]
global-ignores = *.suo *.user bin obj
```

But the global-ignores is really a local global-ignores.  It is local to your machine but global to all your commands / repositories.  Anyone else doing any imports will need their file updated or any projects they import will suffer the conflicts.

Comment: Are you afraid of conflicts? You shouldn't be - they are to be expected in merges. Regarding global ignores: in Subversion 1.8 you can [setup global ignores on the server](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#repos-dictated-config) which filters down into everyone's checkouts.

Comment: You misunderstand.  If you change one line of code then get 200+ conflicts in unrelated files it makes merging more costly than doing the change by hand.  If you do not understand the question ask and I will clarify.

Comment: Sounds like your [mergeinfo](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.mergeinfo) isn't reliable. You could add the global ignores onto the target branch as shown above, then edit the mergeinfo to make it look like the merge happened - _but you must manually merge every change afterwards._ Painful, yes, but worth it in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Visual Studio? Then, use [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net). This will do several things:

- It will automatically not commit special user specific VisualStudio files that are causing you so much heartache into your repository.
- It allows you to use Subversion from inside of VisualStudio. No need for a separate client.
- It will make sure to use `_svn` folders to store Subversion working directory information rather than `.svn.

Also, consider a pre-commit hook that will prevent users from committing these types of files. I have [one](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook) that I've used for years. It can be used to prevent users from committing any files that end in `*.suo`, `.user`, or directories called `bin` and `obj`. This makes sure that other developers in your group don't do nasty stuff.

Comment: Thats good to know.  Can it do imports while ignoring the specified files?  Commits were not the issue, imports were.

Comment: You can [`svnadmin dump`, `svndumpfilter`, and then `svnload`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svndumpfilter) to remove the files from the repo. Otherwise, use the pre-commit hook to stop commits that contain these files

Comment: I didn't know that you can remove files from the repository.  This could help, thanks!